# Access the USB drive from which Ubuntu boots

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

How can I access files stored on the USB drive from which Ubuntu boots? (Using Ubuntu 12.10)

Comment: If you are booting from a live USB, then you would use your file manager to go to the `/` directory, and edit files there.

Are you booting from a USB stick?

Comment: Yes I'am booting from the USB stick and the file manager is able to recognise the disk. The problem is that I'am unable mount the disk and I get a message saying that I'am performing an unauthorised operation.

Comment: That's because the drive is already mounted. It is the root file system so Like DaboRoss said just go to `/` and you should see the contents of your USB drive.

Comment: Are you trying to mount a separate partition?

Comment: No, Im not trying to mount a separate partition.

Answer (score 1):

The content of the USB is mounted under `/cdrom` folder. So, one can browse to that folder by -

- Opening the 'disks' application, and then selecting the drive you want to open (Here it's your pendrive). Then click on '/cdrom', which looks like a hyperlink.
- Or opening Nautilus and going to `/cdrom` directory.

Comment: But I find it quite strange to find my pendrive mounted as a cdrom.

Comment: I found that I'm only able to 'access' the files in the pendrive. I'm unable write files into it.